# Writing testable entrypoints for Azure Functions

Tags: typescript, azure-functions

I  think this question is a more generic JavaScript/TypeScript question, but I'm unsure of the terminology here.

I am writing functions in TypeScript that I compile to JavaScript and then run in Azure Functions. This is  the entry point of one such function:

```js
const queueListener: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const iotHubConnectionString: string = process.env.IOT_HUB_CONNECTION_STRING || ""
        if (iotHubConnectionString === "") {
            throw new CncError("IoT Hub connection string is undefined")
        }

        const cosmosConnectionString: string = process.env.COSMOSDB_CONNECTION_STRING || ""
        if (iotHubConnectionString === "") {
            throw new CncError("Cosmos connection string is undefined")
        }

        const cosmosConnection: CosmosDB = new CosmosDB(cosmosConnectionString, ConnectionStringUtil.getDatabaseNameFromConnectionString(cosmosConnectionString))
        const cosmosService: CosmosService = new CosmosService(cosmosConnection)

        const eventHandler = new EventHandler(context, cosmosService)
        await eventHandler.handleEvent(context.bindings.packageEventTrigger)
    } catch (error) {
        context.log("Failed to handle package event", error)
        if (error instanceof CncError) {
            context.log(error.message)
        }
    }
}

export default queueListener;
```

As you can see I create an instance of a class called `EventHandler`. The reason I'm doing this is that I want to test all important logic and use mocks.

Is there any way I can test this entry point? For instance, I'd like to  verify that `eventHandler.handleEvent()` is called with a proper value.

The only thing I've managed to write tests for are the failures produced when strings are missing from the environment. Jest tests below:

```js
test('Logs exception when iot hub connection string missing', async () => {
    let contextMock: Context = mock<Context>()
    let context = instance(contextMock)

    process.env = { IOT_HUB_CONNECTION_STRING: "" }

    await queueTrigger(context, null)

    verify(contextMock.log("IoT Hub connection string is undefined")).once()
})


test('Logs exception when connection string missing', async () => {
    let contextMock: Context = mock<Context>()
    let context = instance(contextMock)

    process.env = { 
        IOT_HUB_CONNECTION_STRING: "defined",
        COSMOSDB_CONNECTION_STRING: "" 
    }

    await queueTrigger(context, null)

    verify(contextMock.log("Cosmos connection string is undefined")).once()
})
```

The definition for the AzureFunction type is:

```js
export declare type AzureFunction = ((context: Context, ...args: any[]) => Promise<any> | void)
```

How can I structure the functions entrypoint to make it testable?

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is you use `export` instead of `module.exports` which recommended. You can try and refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#configure-function-entry-point.

Comment: Indeed it looks like it will solve my issue. I wonder if I didn't go that way due to typescript type checking. The type package shows my format https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/functions

Comment: I got problem using the format in npmjs.com/package/@azure/functions. It shows "To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension." Did `module.exports` works for you?

Comment: If my answer did a little help, you can accept it as the answer of your question, so more people would see it and get helped, thank you.

Comment: I will as soon as I've had the time

Comment: There shouldn't be anything wrong with exporting a `default` declaration from a module like you do. Typescript compiler will generate the `module.exports = ...` (CommonJS) format compatible with Node (thus Azure runtime). What was the error you were getting?

Comment: I weren't getting any errors, I just didn't know how to write the code to be testable. I couldn't inject mocks into something that was created within the queueListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In TypeScript, use `module.exports` instead of `export`.
- Refer to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#configure-function-entry-point).

[image]

Comment: It works flawlessly, thanks a lot! Code is now fully testable